# CakePHP 3.x select form for nested entities

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Trying to create a form selection input for an array of nested entities. I've achieved it this way "manually", but it doesn't feel very cakey.

```
<select name="restaurant_id" class="form-control" id="restauarnt-id">
  <option value="">Select Restaurant</option>
  <?php foreach($post->city->restaurants as $restauarnt): ?>
    <option value="<?= $restauarnt->id?>"><?= $restauarnt->name ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Something like this feel more right:

```
$this->Form->input('restauarnt_id', ['options' => $post->city->restaurants, 'empty' => 'Select Restaurant', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false]);
```

but that gives me:

```
<select name="restauarnt_id" class="form-control" id="restauarnt-id">    
    <option value="">Select Restaurant</option>
    <option value="0">{"id": 1, "city_id": 1, "name": "Some Place"}</option>
</select>
```

What's the best way to go about it?

(Cake Version 3.x)

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Show us how you're initializing the `$post` variable. It seems most likely that the data you're getting there is not properly formatted to use the "more right" version.

Comment: They're fully hydrated entities, I can access the data in them correctly. 
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Cities' => ['Restaurants']],
        'order' => ['date' => 'ASC']
      ];
Ideally I'd want the contain to be formatted as 'list'

Answer (score 0):

in **Controller** add:

```
$restaurants = $this->Restaurants->find('list');

$this->set(compact('restaurants'));
```

In **View**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('restauarnt_id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $restaurants, 'empty' => __('Select Restaurant'), 'label' => false]) ?>
```

Comment: This would require assigning lft and rgt values in my database to implement the tree behaviour no?

Comment: @KyleGoslan you are right, treeList is for cateegories and subcategories, I edit my answer to change 'treeList'  for 'list'

Answer (score 0):

**in Controller:**

```
$restaurants = $this->[(whatever $post is)]->Cities->Restaurants->find('list'
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'name'
);
$this->set(compact('restaurants'));
```

**in View:**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('retaurant_id', [
    'empty' => '--',
    'label' => 'Restaurants'
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: I know that's the standard way of doing it when I'm concerned with just one post entity. But,I have an array of Post entities all of which have an array of sub-entities, and I'm creating multiple forms one the page.